# changing colors/cycling kind of (java)

Tags: java, loops, colors

I'm trying to get the `Mosaic` to add red, then green, then blue, in a repeated cycle until the colors are white, a.k.a. `(r/g/b/ >= 255)`.

I have written various if statements, since I believe that's the loop I'm looking for. I've come to a stopping point. The problem is that the loop cycles all the way to white, then stays blue (resets the red, I'm assuming. it's more cyan than magenta). I'm assuming this is because the loop never gets to blue after it is relooped in a `while(Mosaic.isOpen())` loop in the `main()` routine. The other version (The one I've posted hereafter, wherein I've become stumped.) repeatedly adds then resets blue (I believe, because it cycles to yellow, then resets to green.).

Here is the for loop being ran and reran by the `main()` routine.

```
  static void colorChange(int x,int y) {
        int red = Mosaic.getRed(x,y);
        int green = Mosaic.getGreen(x,y);
        int blue = Mosaic.getBlue(x,y);
        if (red <= green || red <= blue) {
            if (red <= 240) {
                Mosaic.setColor(x, y, red + 6, green, blue);
            } else {
                Mosaic.setColor(x, y, 0, green, blue);
            } //
        } else if (green <= blue || green <= red) {
            if (green <= 240) {
                Mosaic.setColor(x, y, red, green + 6, blue);
            } else {
                Mosaic.setColor(x,y,red,0,blue);
            } //
        }  else if (blue <= red && blue <= green) {
            if (blue <= 240) {
                Mosaic.setColor(x, y, red, green, blue + 6);
            } else {
                 Mosaic.setColor(x, y, red, green, 0);
            }  //
        }
```

Can anyone see what I might be missing? In case it wasn't clear before, I would like to add red, then the next cycle (since red should be greater than green) it should add green, then the same with blue, until finally resetting the values when they're about to max out.

Comment or email me with any further questions: `philecarpenter@gmail.com` .

Comment: Is there a reason for "&&" in your last if-Statement?

Comment: Oh, no. I mean, I was changing the operators and logical operators around a lot to see what effect it would have. Just didn't change it back before I posted it. There were a few different versions of nested statements and logical comparisons as well.

Comment: I think it will never execute last `else if` statement because if `red <= green` is `false` in `if` then  `green <= red` will definitely be `true` in first `else if`.

Comment: I see what you mean. It's slightly confusing to think in Java still, could you explain it further or maybe help with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean redSmallerGreen = (red <= green);
boolean greenSmallerBlue = (green <= blue);

//What happens here?!
boolean allGreater240 = (red >= 240 && blue >= 240 && green >= 240);

if (redSmallerGreen) {
    Mosaic.setColor(x, y, red<=240?red+6:0,green,blue); 
} else if (greenSmallerBlue) {
    Mosaic.setColor(x, y, red,green<=240?green+6:0,blue);   
} else if (allgreater240) {
    //?!
} else {
    Mosaic.setColor(x, y, red,green,blue<=240?blue+6:0);    
}
```

What happens? At some point, red, green and blue will all be greater 240. Now blue will reset to 0 and increased to 240 again while red and green stay the same.
Maybe this helps you solving your problem. I would have wirrten a comment but it would have been unreadable.

I did not test my code, just wrote it down to get a imagination of what you / I are doing here :)

Edit: Reverse

```
int step = 6;

public void yourFunction() {

    (...)

    boolean redSmallerGreen = (red <= green);
    boolean greenSmallerBlue = (green <= blue);

    boolean allSmaller0 = (red <= 0 && blue <= 0 && green <= 0); 
    boolean allGreater240 = (red >= 240 && blue >= 240 && green >= 240);

    if (allSmaller0) {
        step = 6;
    }
    if (allGreater240) {
        step = -6;
    }

    if (redSmallerGreen) {
        Mosaic.setColor(x, y, red+step,green,blue); 
    } else if (greenSmallerBlue) {
        Mosaic.setColor(x, y, red,green+step,blue); 
    } else {
        Mosaic.setColor(x, y, red,green,blue+step); 
    }
}
```

Comment: The one thing I don't understand is the statement `red<=240?red+6:0`. What is that saying?

Comment: @PhilC.
if (red<=240) then red+6 else 0

("?" equals "then"
 ":" equals "else")

Comment: Wow, this seems to be a wonderful solution to my/our problem! Would it ever execute the second `else if` (`allgreater240`)? I think not, but not sure at this point haha!

Comment: in my code, if allgreater240 the Mosaic would not change the color anymore because no Mosaic.setColor is called.

Comment: Oh, i think it will execute after I think about it! I should presumably reset them all, but I think that will look bad. Time to write a reverse statement..?

Comment: @PhilC.
I added a reverse function to my original answer. Hope it works :D

Comment: It just will not work. I'm going to keep thinking about your versions, and write out some algorithms on paper. Always seems to help. I'll let you know when I conquer it, and I'll send you the file! Thanks for your help.